# Java script sorting not working properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting

Im trying to sort json objects from a mongodb of this form:

```
{"_id" : 99999999, "dni": 99999999, "marks" : 7}
```

I have an array of objects like this and im trying to sort it by "marks":

```
myArray.sort(function( o1, o2 ){ return o1.marks < o2.marks });
```

But it not seems to be working...
What Im I doing wrong?

Comment: prove it. what goes in, what comes out, and what did you expect to come out.

Comment: There is a typo on function, perhaps that also does not help?

Comment: Does it work if you type function, and not fuction ?

Comment: "function" not "fuction" !!!

Comment: Sorry guys I just retyped it bad, im my code was well, the answer below just works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
myArray.sort(function( o1, o2 ){ return o1.marks - o2.marks });
```

The sort function should not return boolean, but a negative, 0, or positive value. [Here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Returning `0` when the values are equal is important, because the sorting algorithm will do many comparisons and it is not guaranteed that one element is always on the left side of the comparison.

And depending on your indexes you could as well let MongoDB do the sorting:

```
db.col.find({}).sort({marks: 1});
```

Comment: Should still work, and I would think `return o1.marks < o2.marks ? 1 : -1;` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @adeneo it is not two-state, but three-state. Your suggestion is correct if you have unique values.

Comment: Does it matter, `o1` is either placed before or after `o2` based on what is returned, if `0` is returned they can't be placed on top of each other.